# Support to convert time zone to IST from any other time zone in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I,m using following versions of Ruby and Rails
**Ruby : 2.0.0p481** & 
**Rails : 4.1.1**

Could not find any method in **DateTime** `class` to convert time to IST.

Tried `DateTime.in_time_zone` in IRB, could convert IST to EST but not vise versa.

```
    2.0.0-p481 :003 > date = "Thu Jan 07 2016 16:20:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
    2.0.0-p481 :003 > date = date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
    2.0.0-p481 :003 > date
      => Thu, 07 Jan 2016 05:50:00 EST -05:00
```

Wanted to know how can I convert other tine zones to IST.
Please let me know if there is any way from which I can achive this.

Comment: Which time zone's date/time you want to convert to IST?  What is the input in your case?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert to IST from any timezone. Say from EST [ Fri Dec 04 2015 11:35:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) ] to IST. I could not find anything in ruby to achieve this.

Comment: Where do you get these EST times from?  Are they texts that you parse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone` provide the names of all timezones. You can list out all timezones by doing

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

For just `US` timezones

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:name)
```

So change your time with the available timezones. Like this

```
irb> date = DateTime.now
=> Thu, 31 Dec 2015 22:15:59 +0530

# convert to EST
irb> date_est = date.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
=> Thu, 31 Dec 2015 11:45:59 EST -05:00

# convert to IST
irb> date_ist = date_est.in_time_zone("Chennai")
=> Thu, 31 Dec 2015 22:15:59 IST +05:30
```

Happy coding...