# ruby,Get a datetime from sqlite3,always presents 2000-01-01

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, sqlite

I want to get the value of "start_time" from "activities"(a table name in sqlite3) by using ruby on rails. And I meet some problems.

In the sqlite3, the value of "start_time" is "2016-01-04 08:00:00", and it's a correct value.

But when I got the value by using ruby , the value is "2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC".

```
    @activities = Activity.all()
    @activities.each do |activity|
        puts activity.start_date
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` method to remove the `UTC`.

```
@activities = Activity.all()
@activities.each do |activity|
    puts activity.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

If you want to set you local `time_zone` instead of `UTC` then set it to your `config/application.rb` file

```
config.time_zone = '<your time zone>'
```

For getting your local `time_zone` please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545976/support-to-convert-time-zone-to-ist-from-any-other-time-zone-in-ruby/34549237#34549237).

Comment: thank you , and I have added ".strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")", but the output also is "2000-01-01". the correct value in database is "2016-01-06".